# How can I exclude some entities in "drush entity:delete" command?

Tags: 8, drush

I want to delete all content of custom entity type except some specific items, I found `drush entity:delete CUSTOM_TYPE` command to delete all contents but couldn't exclude some items from deletion in this command, does it have any option like `--exclude ID1, ID2, ID3, ...`?

Or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It shouldn't be to difficult to add this option to the [`entity:delete`](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/commit/b213ec14e6658e3cd42a384feca496a3889ce2f4) command. You should open an issue as feature request on GitHub.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a feature request for Drush that should be handled in Drush's issue queue on GitHub.

Comment: @leymannx I'm not just focusing on using `entity:delete` command, I asked for other solutions as well, the `entity:delete` command that I mention here is just the result of my researches before asking the question, so it doesn't seems to be an off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ drush entity:delete node --bundle=article --exclude=9,14,81
```

or

```
$ drush entity:delete CUSTOM_TYPE --exclude=1,2,3
```

I added the `--exclude` option as a pull request [#4175](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/4175) to Drush. It also works in Drush 9, so you could use this pull request to patch your local Drush like that:

```
"patches": {
    "drush/drush": {
        "Add option to exclude entities by ID to entity:delete command.": "https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/pull/4175.patch"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can run `drush entity:delete --help` to see available options.

Answer (score 3):

ok mate you want other options and here is the answer:

if you look at

vendor/drush/drush/src/Drupal/Commands/core/EntityCommands.php

you can see the what the function does....

now you need to learn how to make a custom drush commands i assume you are using drush 9  so you can just run:

"drush  generate drush-command-file"

or read: https://www.axelerant.com/resources/team-blog/how-to-write-custom-drush-9-commands-for-drupal-8

this will create:
modules/custom/YOURMODULE/drush.services.yml
and 
modules/custom/YOURMODULE/src/Commands/YOURMODULECommands.php

now have a look at the following working example ...

```
<?php
/**
 * Command delete some stuff
 *
 * @param $entity_type
 *   Argument for entity type.
 * @param $exclude
 *   Argument for exclude delete of ids.
 *
 * @param array $options
 *   An associative array of options whose values come from ...
 *
 * @option option-name
 *   Description
 * 
 * @usage deletethings-commandName foo
 *   Usage description
 *
 * @command deletethings:commandName
 * @aliases delete-my-stuff
 */
 public function commandName($entity_type, $exclude,  $options = ['option-name' => 'default']) {
$this->logger()->success(dt($entity_type));
$this->logger()->success(dt($exclude));
$exclude_ids= [];
if ($exclude !== 'none') {
  $exclude_ids = explode(',', $exclude);
}


// now do the delete stuff
$storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type);
if (is_object($storage)) {
  $all = $storage->loadMultiple();
  if (count($all) !== 0) {
    foreach ($all as $entity) {
      $id = $entity->id();
      if (!in_array($id, $exclude_ids)) {
        // kill with fire.
        $entity->delete();
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

With that you can run:

drush  delete-my-stuff ENTITY_TYPE 5,6,10

example: drush  delete-my-stuff node 5,6,10

this would then allow you to delete all items of your entity except for "5,6,10" - which are ids you want to keep

or drush  delete-my-stuff ENTITY_TYPE none (to delete all)

remember to run drush cr and drush cc (1) so drush will recognise the new command